# How can I find the RGB data for an .svs image file in Java?

Tags: java, image, matrix, rgb, tiff

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to java, and I've been trying to do my best to learn as much about the language as possible. Recently I've started learning the logic behind analyzing images pixel by pixel for their RGB data. Whilst doing this I stumbled upon svs files which are these extremely high quality files that are basically multilayered tiffs.I've explored several open source projects that decode and display .svs images, but couldn't find the algorithms or code in which they decoded the .svs files. Could someone direct me to what file(s) inside of the open source project that would contain the algorithm to decode an svs file, as I'm deeply interested in how one would go about decoding such a large and complex image file, or could someone help me with an algorithm to decode a .svs file in Java. Thanks in advance!

links:

https://github.com/openslide/openslide-java

https://github.com/imagej/imagej

Comment: As you say, SVS files *"are basically multilayered tiffs"*. However, the TIFF format allows different pixel formats, image layouts, compression types, etc. It's quite complex. I downloaded a couple of SVS sample files, and they contained JPEG and JPEG 2000 (J2K) data. So there's no single algorithm to decode them, you need to parse the TIFF structure, then decompress and re-assemble the image from the strips/tiles. My [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library seens to open them fine, except for the J2K data, if you want to look at the source, or just use it.

Comment: @haraldK thank you so much for replying. Could you maybe elaborate on how I would parse the TIFF structure, decompress, and then reassemble it. How would I use your TwelveMonkeys Library to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

SVS files are produced by Aperio scanners, so you need the Aperio decoder from openslide:

https://github.com/openslide/openslide/blob/master/src/openslide-vendor-aperio.c

openslide have some docs on the format here:

http://openslide.org/formats/aperio/

It's interesting to understand the details, but perhaps not very useful. If you want to read it yourself from Java, you can use the excellent openslide binding, or a libtiff binding plus a lot of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the `.svs` files created by Aperio, are just [TIFF files](http://openslide.org/formats/aperio/) (with some limitations, and some minor extensions).

It is not clear from the question whether you just want to read images from such files using an existing library, or if you want to develop such a solution for yourself (for educational purposes or otherwise).

If the latter is the case, you really should read the [TIFF 6.0 specification](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf) along with the Adobe Tech Notes specifying "new" JPEG compression and and what you can find documented about the Aperio SVS format. You can also look at the source code of existing libraries. Describing the steps necessary to implement a TIFF/SVS reader/decoder from scratch is *way* beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer.

If, on the other hand, you just want to open such a file in Java, you should be able to open most of them simply by using `ImageIO` and a TIFF plugin*.

Code could be as simple as:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/your.svs"));
```

This will read the first, and according to what I understand from the specification, the full resolution image in the file.

To read specific image (or, all images if you add a loop) in the file, the code becomes a little more verbose:

```
// Create input stream
File file = new File("path/to/your.svs");
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)) {
    // Get the reader
    Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

    if (!readers.hasNext()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No reader for: " + file);
    }

    ImageReader reader = readers.next();

    try {
        reader.setInput(input);

        // Optionally, listen for read warnings, progress, etc.
        reader.addIIOReadWarningListener(...);
        reader.addIIOReadProgressListener(...);

        // Use reader.getNumImages(true) to get the number of images
        // in the file, and optionally add a loop to read all the images.

        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

        // Optionally, control read settings like subsampling, source region or destination etc.
        param.setSourceSubsampling(...);
        param.setSourceRegion(...);
        param.setDestination(...);
        // ...

        // Finally read the image, using settings from param
        BufferedImage image = reader.read(0, param);

        // Optionally, read thumbnails, etc...
        int numThumbs = reader.getNumThumbnails(0);
        // ...

        // Optionally, get the image metadata (ie. to get the custom Aperio 
        // values from the ImageDescription tag for further processing)
        IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
        // ...
    }
    finally {
        // Dispose reader in finally block to avoid memory leaks
        reader.dispose();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to skip images that are too large to display in Java (`.svs` files may contain images that are too large for a `BufferedImage`...) or have a custom compression not supported by the reader (`.svs` files may contain images compressed both in baseline JPEG and custom JPEG 2000).

You probably need to read up on the specification to see the order of images, what image is a "thumbnail", a "macro" and a "label" image. I think the "thumbnail" is always a JPEG stream.

---

*) TIFF plugins for ImageIO:

- The most common TIFF plugin for ImageIO is JAI ImageIO (`jai_imageio.jar`), but it is no longer in development, and I have not tested it with `.svs` files.
- My own project, [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys), is actively developed and contains a TIFF plugin that aims to be compatible with the one from JAI, but fixing bugs and adding missing features. I have tested this plugin with some sample `.svs` files, and it can read them, except the ones having a non-standard (as in "not in the TIFF specification") JPEG 2000 compression.
- There are TIFF plugins that I know of, but I haven't tried any of these.
- There might also be special purpose Aperio SVS plugins available, that I don't know of.